# .htaccess rewrite this/kind/of/address to this_kind_of_address.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi stackoverflow users!

I need to set an url rewrite via access to make these url requests:

`this/kind/of/url`

or

`this/kind/of/url.php`

point to this file:

`this_kind_of_url.php`

Basically I need to convert all "/" that I get in the url to a "_" and add a .php extension if not provided. I thought it was not *too* complicated at first but now I'm almost losing my head on it since I'm quite new to .htaccess.

Thanx in advance for your precious help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1_$2 [E=SLASH:Y,DPI]

RewriteCond %{ENV:SLASH} Y
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)(?:\.php)$ /$1.php [L,R=301]
```

It's a little tricky to get your head around, but the first rule checks to make sure the request isn't for an existing file or directory. And if there' a slash in it, then replace it with a `_` and set the environment variable "SLASH". This rule will loop until there are no more `/`'s in the URI.

That's where the second rule comes into play. If the environment variable is set, and there are no more slashes in the URI, then it redirects the browser and adds a `.php` to the end if there isn't one.

So:

```
/this/kind/of/url
```

is redirected to

```
/this_kind_of_url.php
```

Comment: Thanx man! There's a problem with DPI flag that seems to be not supported in the version I'm dealing with but if I try to remove it it works.

Comment: @Ace_Gentile the `DPI` flag is used to counter a bug with apache where the PATH_INFO gets appended to the end for apparently no reason, if your version doesn't experience this bug, then you don't need it.

Comment: Luckily my version is not affected by this bug and it works without DPI flag.. thanks again!